Bound on the sectional curvature of a product manifold
My question is related to this question by User1.
Consider two Riemannian manifolds $(M, g_M), (N, g_N)$, for which we know that their sectional curvatures $K_M, K_N$ are bounded from above by some positive constants $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 > 0$, $K_M \leq \alpha_1$, $K_N \leq \alpha_2$.
If we now consider the product $(M \times N, g_{M \times N})$, where $g_{M\times N}$ is the standard product metric on $M\times N$, what can we say about the bound of $K_{M\times N}$, the sectional curvature of the product?
I know that $K_{M\times N}$ can be zero, and I guess that a very naive bound would be $2\max\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2\}$. Nevertheless, in the question that I cited in the beginning of my post, for two copies of $\mathbb{S}^n$, one would get a tighter bound. Can this fact be generalised to my setting?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Have you tried to compute the curvature tensor?

Certainly $\max\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2\}$ is the optimal upper bound on the curvature of the product metric.  The other question you linked is not considering the product metric, but rather the product of suitably rescaled metrics.

Thank you for your answer! I had noted the difference but still it was somehow related to my question.
Could I see a proof / reference for the claim of $\max{\alpha_1, \alpha_2}$ being the optimal upper bound?

@Pablo, I suggest you try to prove it yourself by computing the curvature tensor.
